# Solving $\cos(x/2) = \sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone give me just a hint as to how to go about solving this? Yes it is for homework, but I don't want an answer, just a bit of guidance. I'm thinking the half angle formula for the first bit, but it doesn't seem to look right.

$$\cos(x/2)-\sin(x) = 0$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y=\frac{x}{2}$, so that your equation is
$$\cos(y)=\sin(2y).$$
Do you know any formulas that you can use here?

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I needed to get the brain started :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try rewriting $\sin x$ as $$\sin x =2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}.$$